# How to drop records having a particular string which is present in multiple columns in a DataFrame in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a huge data frame with many rows and columns. Some columns contain a string `'Varies with device'`.
I want to drop those records with this particular string. I know how to drop if a particular string is present **in a particular column.**. but I want to know a method when that particular string is present **in multiple columns**

I tried

```
df2=df1[df1['Size','Current Ver','Android Ve'].str.contains('Varies with device')==False]
```

I got error for above input

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution:

```py
df2 = df.drop(
    df[
        df.apply(
            lambda row: row.apply(
                lambda value: True if 'Varies with device' in str(value) else False
            ).any(), axis=1
        )
    ].index
)
```

**For example:**

```py
# Define the data
data = {
    'Name': ['Varies with device', 'Anna', 'Peter', 'Linda', 'Varies with device Bar'],
    'Age': [23, 'Varies with device foo', 35, 'Foo Varies with device', 29],
    'City': ['New York', 'Los Angeles', 'Chicago', 'Houston', 'Phoenix'],
    'Salary': [70000, 80000, 120000, 90000, 110000]
}

# Create the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
# Prints:
#
#                      Name                     Age         City  Salary
# 0      Varies with device                      23     New York   70000
# 1                    Anna  Varies with device foo  Los Angeles   80000
# 2                   Peter                      35      Chicago  120000
# 3                   Linda  Foo Varies with device      Houston   90000
# 4  Varies with device Bar                      29      Phoenix  110000

df2 = df.drop(
    df[
        df.apply(
            lambda row: row.apply(
                lambda value: True if 'Varies with device' in str(value) else False
            ).any(), axis=1
        )
    ].index
)
print(df2)
# Prints:
#
#     Name Age     City  Salary
# 2  Peter  35  Chicago  120000
```

**Or:**

```py
df2 = df[
    ~df.apply(
        lambda row: row.apply(
            lambda value: True if 'Varies with device' in str(value) else False
        ).any(), axis=1
    )
]
```

**Or:**

```py
df[~df.select_dtypes(object).apply(lambda row: row.str.contains('Varies with device').any(), axis=1)]
```